# Converting Python Code to apk for Android?

Tags: python, apk, kivy

I have written a `Python` code which imports libraries like `numpy, scipy, keras` (deep learning).

Is it possible to convert it to mobile `.apk` using say `kivy`?
I couldn't find any documentation specifying it is possible or not possible. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

While there is a numpy recipe, i believe there is no scipy or keras one, and it's certainly going to be quite some work to do them, so while theorically yes, python-for-android would do the job, in practice, you'll have to get your hands dirty to get that going.

Comment: open cv recipe is available?

Comment: yes https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/opencv

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about [Python for Android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android). You have to give it a try.